# Item count in a table using SQL

Tags: sql, count, vertica, apriori

I want to count the frequency of all the items in a table. My starting table is something like this:

```
+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 |
+------+------+
| A    | Z    |
| B    | Y    |
| A    | Y    |
+------+------+
```

And I would like to get the following result:

```
+------+-------+
| Item | Count |
+------+-------+
| A    |     2 |
| B    |     1 |
| Y    |     2 |
| Z    |     1 |
+------+-------+
```

I was thinking that the easiest way would be to append all Columns together to create a single Column. With that I could apply a COUNT and GROUP BY operation. The question is, how can I append multiple columns into one column.
I need this to implement an Apriori algorithm on my table in a Vertica DB. This is the first step to get an item count.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Unpivot* the data and do the count

Try this way

```
select Item,count(1)
From 
(
select col1 as Item from yourtable
union all
select col2 from yourtable
) A
Group by item
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! I knew that there was a simple way, but I guess to stupid to use google the right way.